# Issue getting a WCF service to listen on the same URI for different POST requests

Tags: c#, windows, wcf

I am having issues getting a WCF service to listen on a URI and process differently based on the type of POST that it recieves...

Example:

WCF service is exposed like so.

```
http://localhost/test
```

The endpoint above will be receiving the following POST requests:

```
POST http://localhost/test HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.25.0
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Host: localhost
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 42

{"input":"example string"}
```

The endpoint will also receive the following POST request on the same URI :

```
POST http://localhost/test HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.25.0
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Host: localhost
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 42

{"input":"example string","turtle":"I Love Turtles"}
```

I want to be able to process the requests differently based on the content of the request body, I tried this:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        UriTemplate = "test/",
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string PostWithOneBis(string input,string turtle);
    string PostWithOnePrim(string input);
```

As explained I would like to enter the first function or the second based on the request that I receive. I do not want to setup a different URI to handle these different request types...

I hope my explanation is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each [OperationContract] can only modify one method, so your code does not solve the problem, you can make the turtle default value null to solve this problem,for the received request, you need to determine whether the **turtle** is empty to know which method to run,here is a demo:

**Class**

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
    UriTemplate = "test/{input}/{turtle=null}",
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string PostWithOne(string input, string turtle);
```

**Implementation class**

```
    public string PostWithOne(string input, string turtle)
    {
        if (turtle == null)  //  string PostWithOnePrim(string input);
        {
            return "string PostWithOnePrim(string input)";
        }
        else
        {            //   string PostWithOneBis(string input,string turtle);
            return "string PostWithOneBis(string input,string turtle)";
        }
    }
```

We judge in PostWithOne whether to use the PostWithOneBis method or the PostWithOnePrim method.

[image]

If you don’t pass parameters in the URI, **PostWithOne** will receive any json, and you also need to judge the obtained json to determine whether to use the PostWithOnePrim method or the PostWithOneBis method.

**Class**

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
    UriTemplate = "test/",
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string PostWithOne(string input, string turtle);
```

[image]

WCF Rest service judges different requests by URI rather than by request content, so there is no difference between **PostWithOneBis (string input, string turtle)** and **PostWithOnePrim (string input)** for WCF.

**One UriTemplate and one [OperationContract] can only modify one method, and UriTemplate cannot be repeated in a service.**

Feel free to let me know if the problem persists.